# Failed to process package 'cartographer':

Tags: ros, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i build the cartographer_ros ,errors happened as follow:

```
[6/90] Building documentation.
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
[9/90] Building CXX object cartographe...eal_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o
FAILED: /usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include -I. -I/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer -isystem /usr/include/lua5.2 -I/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/common/{Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}     -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror=format-security -Werror=return-type -Werror=uninitialized -MMD -MT cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o -MF "cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o.d" -o cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o -c /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc
In file included from /opt/eigen/Eigen/Geometry:39:0,
                 from /opt/eigen/Eigen/Dense:6,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/internal/numeric_diff.h:40,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/dynamic_numeric_diff_cost_function.h:70,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/ceres.h:44,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/common/math.h:25,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/probability_grid.h:28,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.h:44,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc:17:
/opt/eigen/Eigen/src/Geometry/Rotation2D.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar> Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar>::operator*(const Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar>&) const [with _Scalar = double]’:
/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.cc:123:71:   required from here
/opt/eigen/Eigen/src/Geometry/Rotation2D.h:78:28: error: could not convert ‘(((Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar)((const Eigen::Rotation2D<double>*)this)->Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::m_angle) + ((Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar)other.Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::m_angle))’ from ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar {aka double}’ to ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<double>’
   { return m_angle + other.m_angle; }
                            ^
[9/90] Building CXX object cartographe...dir/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o
FAILED: /usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include -I. -I/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer -I/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/common/{Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} -isystem /usr/include/lua5.2     -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror=format-security -Werror=return-type -Werror=uninitialized -MMD -MT cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_fast_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o -MF "cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_fast_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o.d" -o cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/CMakeFiles/mapping_2d_scan_matching_fast_correlative_scan_matcher.dir/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc.o -c /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc
In file included from /opt/eigen/Eigen/Geometry:39:0,
                 from /opt/eigen/Eigen/Dense:6,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/internal/numeric_diff.h:40,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/dynamic_numeric_diff_cost_function.h:70,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/include/ceres/ceres.h:44,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/common/math.h:25,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/probability_grid.h:28,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.h:33,
                 from /home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc:17:
/opt/eigen/Eigen/src/Geometry/Rotation2D.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar> Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar>::operator*(const Eigen::Rotation2D<Scalar>&) const [with _Scalar = double]’:
/home/exbot/cartographer/src/cartographer/cartographer/mapping_2d/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher.cc:270:73:   required from here
/opt/eigen/Eigen/src/Geometry/Rotation2D.h:78:28: error: could not convert ‘(((Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar)((const Eigen::Rotation2D<double>*)this)->Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::m_angle) + ((Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar)other.Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::m_angle))’ from ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar {aka double}’ to ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<double>’
   { return m_angle + other.m_angle; }
                            ^
[9/90] Building CXX object cartographe..._test.dir/laser_fan_inserter_test.cc.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
<== Failed to process package 'cartographer': 
  Command '/home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/env.sh ninja -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/exbot/cartographer/build_isolated/cartographer && /home/exbot/cartographer/install_isolated/env.sh ninja -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

i have rebuilt many times but the errors are still have.My ROS is indigo,ubuntu 14.04 x86.But I have succeed to build cartographer in the other computer which has ROS indigo ,ubuntu 14.04 x64.plz help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245442/failed-to-process-package-%27cartographer%27:/) by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:
I think this is specific enough to be solved by the Cartographer devs themselves. I recommend you report this to [cartographer_ros/issues](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_ros/issues). Please report back if/when you resolve this.

**Comment by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on 2016-10-11**:
I have get the reply from github that X86 is unsopported.But they also say that the errors may not be caused by X86 or X64.I decided to change to X64 to solve it ........

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:
Could you provide a link to the github issue that you reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Resolved here: https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer/issues/42

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0